# how to insert array into embeded document in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a document like this:

```
b = { "_id":"10001", "comments":[{"comid":"3","comtime":"2014","author":"jenny"}]}
```

I want to insert another one like:

```
c = {"comid":"34","comtime":"2015","author":"jack"}
```

into comid whose value is "3".
the result I want is :

```
{
        "_id" : "10001",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "comid" : "3",
                        "comtime" : "2014",
                        "author" : "jenny",
                        "replycomment" : [
                                {
                                        "comid" : "34",
                                        "comtime" : "2015",
                                        "author" : "jack"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

exactly I want to have another embedded document in the array for replied comments.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nee to use the [`update_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method and the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/update/pull/) update operator.

```
replycomment = {"comid": "34", "comtime": "2015", "author": "jack"}
collection.update_one(
    {"comments.comid": "3"}, 
    {"$push": {"comments.$.replycomment": replycomment}}
)
```